# What is infinity to the zeroth power?

Tags: exponentiation, infinity

I am not happy with the answers posted to similar questions.

For example, in:

[What is infinity to the power zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714170/what-is-infinity-to-the-power-zero)

the accepted answer is 1, which is definitely wrong.

I think the answer is any non-zero, non-one, non-infinite number.  Is this correct?

Looking for the solution to:   $(1/0)^0$

Comment: What is infinity?

Comment: And what is a power ?

Comment: Please either remove the downvotes or delete the answer.  (One or the other, I don't care.....)

Comment: (For future reference) you are expected to provide context. You stated that you are unhappy with answers posted to similar questions. You should ***reference*** those posts and specify which parts are unsatisfactory to you.

Comment: @Jiminion I think neither will happen, in the short term. As for the reason I think this question is unclear: I don't see why you think what you suggest is true, since actually $\lim_{k\to\infty} k^{1/k}=1$.

Comment: The question didn't ask about the limit.  $1^\infty = 1$.  The limit is problematic because infinity is not a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) and as such cannot be assigned any value.

It is better expressed as $\lim_\limits{{x\to \infty}\\,\\{y\to 0}}x^y$.

As commented by Did, it is true that $x^y$ has no limit when $x\to \infty$ and $y\to 0$.

And $\infty^0$ has no definite meaning in mathematics. It is basically some kind of a meaningless statement where the notation of infinity has been wrongly used since infinity is not a number, it is a *concept*. To speak of infinity, I must add the following:

> In standard real analysis, the symbol $\infty$ is simply used to
>   denote an unbounded limit. Whenever the symbol is used, in series and
>   integrals, for example, it has a precise definition with
>   epsilon/delta. Similarly, in set theory, it also has a precise
>   definition; we say a set $S$ is infinite if there is no bijection from
>   $S$ to a bounded subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Reason for Downvote???

Comment: After the (good) initial sentence, I was expecting to see the argument that $x^y$ has no limit when $x\to\infty$ and $y\to0$, unfortunately, next, we are summoned to believe that the "better" explanation of the limit is as the limit of $x^{1/x}$ (an assertion with which one can disagree).

Comment: As asked, what the question poses isn't even, in my opinion, an indeterminate form as usually understood in limits. Perhaps this answer can mislead someone in believing $\;\infty^0\;$ has some definite meaning in mathematics, which I think it doesn't.

Comment: @Joanpemo: I agree. I was thinking of writing something similar until I saw your comment.

Comment: @Joanpemo Is it better addressed now?

Comment: @Did Do you want me to add some more information?

Comment: I would say the precise definition of $inf$ would be $1/0$.

Comment: @Jiminion No, not at all. Infinity is a mathematical concept. It *seriously does not* mean $\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: The current version is much better. One remaining problem is that you use "concept" in a bizarre way (and one which would make every philosopher cringe...).

Comment: It can mean more than one thing.  That is one of them.  (Note that I agree that it is not a number.)

Comment: @Did Why would you say that? I did not want to mean something bizarre.

Comment: @Jiminion Note that division by zero is not defined and hence $\frac{1}{0}$ is meaningless and undefined. Do you get it now?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I think it is better now thought the very first words "it is an..." screech to me.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree.  Using limits,  $1/0$ is pretty clearly either infinity or negative infinity.

Comment: @Jiminion Your use of the word "or" already makes what you say, in my opinion, pretty non-clear

Comment: $1/0$ is pretty clearly either infinity and/or negative infinity.  Either or both.